# Determine the number of ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_{(13)}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{13}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

$\mathbb{Z}_{(13)}$ is the set of all reduced fractions where the denominator is a power of $13$.
 I have absolutely no idea how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ the ring of $13$-adic integers or the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It's the quotient ring. $\mathbb{Z}_{13}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$.

Comment: Do you insist that $\varphi(1) = 1$ for your ring homomorphisms? Either way, there aren't many.

Comment: @Quasicoherent no. $\phi(1)$ can is not restricted to equal $1$.

Comment: @D.Brito All right, then $\varphi(1)^2 = \varphi(1^2) = \varphi(1)$, which leaves two possibilities for $\varphi(1)$, and I claim that this choice determines the map completely.

Comment: Ok, of course, through the separation of sums I can find $\varphi(a)$ for any $a$.